# Probability: PDF and CDF of a disc

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A point is chosen at random from a disc of radius 1. We use the uniform distribution on the disc meaning that the probability of a subset of the disc is equal to the area of the subset divided by π, the area of the disc. Let R be the distance from the point to the center of the disc. So R is a continuous random variable with range [0, 1]. Find the pdf of R.

So far I have that F(r)= r^2 (the cdf), so therefore f(r)=2r from [0,1]...is this the pdf for R?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Answer check- Does your pdf integrate to $1$?